# How to increase margin between search menu option items in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using Ag-grid-enterprise and I'm troubling with increasing the gap between menu items in the search tab.
for example :

[image]

The default gap between those items is 20px, and I want to override this and create something more like this :

[image]

How do I achieve this?
which classes I need to override? or any other solution.

Thanks for the help

Comment: are you using native js, or angular, vue or react?

Comment: Hey I'm using React